# How do I use history prop with other props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, history

I'm using `react-router-dom` with `react`. I'm trying to have other props with the `history prop`

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent({ history }) {
   function redirect() {
      history.push('/path');
   }

   return (
      <>
         <button onClick={redirect}>Some Button</button>
      </>
   );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**This will work, but if I put another prop like this**

```
function MyComponent({myFunction, history}) {}
```

**This wouldn't work**

*Is there any alternatives to this, or am I doing something wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use [`useHistory()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook from **react-router-dom**. Read from the documentation:

> The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

Try as the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent({ myFunction }) { // here still you can pass other props
   let history = useHistory(); // meanwhile you have the history object

   function redirect() {
      history.push('/path');
   }

   return <>
      <button onClick={redirect}>Some Button</button>
   </>
}

export default MyComponent;
```

If you need a fully working example, please find one of my GitHub repositiries below:
https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples

I suggest to take a look at [this file](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-router-programmatically-redirect-examples/blob/master/src/UseHistoryAction/index.tsx) from there. I have already included the essential working example above in my code snippet.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this - you can receive as many props as you want.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent() {
const history = useHistory();
   function redirect() {
      history.push('/path');
   }

   return (
      <>
         <button onClick={redirect}>Some Button</button>
      </>
   );
}

export default MyComponent;
```